# Object expanding on rotation

Tags: origin

I am making a model with a hierarchy of different parts, with their origins connected to another piece in the model. I am trying to animate with this model, and a piece is expanding upward as it rotates around the origin. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Probably this piece has inhomogeneous scale. Apply scale on it with Ctrl+A